# Куда вставлять List-Unsubscribe?

Tags: html, email

При формировании email-рассылки во многих инструкциях советуют вставлять List-Unsubscribe.
Не могу понять, куда именно вставлять? Пишут, что в заголовок. В какой заголовок? Прямо в заголовок письма? Или в теле письма как-то особым образом оформить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Пишут, что в заголовок. В какой заголовок? Прямо в заголовок письма?
>   Или в теле письма как-то особым образом оформить?

То, что называете "заголовком письма", по факту является темой (Subject) письма, само же письмо в его исходном виде состоит из двух частей: заголовки и тело письма, и имеет примерно такой вид:

```
From: ivan@petrov.ru  -|
To: petr@ivanov.ru     | Вот эти поля называются заголовками письма
Subject: Болтовня     -|

Привет, как дела?      | А вот это является телом письма
```

Таким образом, заголовок List-Unsubscribe можно добавить в письмо на момент формирования письма в коде программы, либо с помощью почтовых агентов и дополнений к ним, которые позволяют произвольно редактировать остальные заголовки письма.

Answer (score 2):

List-Unsubscribe нужно добавлять в заголовки письма. Например вот так:

```
  $mail = new \PHPMailer;
  $mail->addCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe",'<mailto:unsubscribe@example.com?subject=unsubscribe&body='.$message_id.'>, <'.$recipient['substitution_data']['UNSUB'].'>');
```